# Cannot retrieve value from application state

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to create and read a global variable by using the application state.

In default.aspx I have this line in Page_Load

```
    Application("myValue") = "theValue"
```

In the class Bomb (placed in App_Code directory), i try to retrieve the value

```
    Dim s As String = Application("myValue")
```

but here I get an error message saying "Application is not declared. It may be inaccesible due to its protection level"

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the current context of the application, or pass in the context.

E.g.:

```
Dim s As String = HttpContext.Current.Application("myValue").ToString()
```